# Read facebook URL in java

Tags: java, facebook

I searched a lot, read many blogs, articles, tutorials. But still there is no straight forward solution to my thought about reading facebook URL in java.

I know that I have to use OAuth, some other autorizations. All of them explains for the app login only.

I am reading this Url https://www.facebook.com/mohan.sunder.12 in my Java code using `URLConnection`.

I am reading the response from the connection in html file.Then, I am opening the html file in browser, but the page shows only login page of facebook.

How do I see this page as it is from java code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the entire facebook page using Java. You need to use api functions such as specified in [this link here](http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html). It specifies how to comment, how to search for posts, and so on. I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should add facebook cookie like this.you can get facebook cookie from page inspect.Now facebook hide their HTML so you can not read HTML file like this.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.har.com");
                System.out.println(url);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty(
                        "Cookie",
                        "datr=llhfWUipxjYoopesqYRfwauu; "
                                + "fr=05mmYQ8tPzse8Vh8A.AWUygf3_G8-tUg15fdgsOeopVuI.BZX1iW.dw.AAA.0.0.BZX1ij.AWUtvdAb; "
                                + "lu=gA; "
                                + "locale=en_US; "
                                + "c_user=100019219509174; "
                                + "xs=16%3ALUjK-gCfcctnLA%3A3%3A1499420835%3A-1%3A-1");
```